# How to fix "infinite redirect loop" in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect, sharepoint

I'm new on Javascript and I am setting up a multilanguage Sharepoint. I want to have a code into each page which would check the user email and the language in the URL (portuguese or spanish) and redirect (or not) to the correct language URL.

The conditions are working but it is on an infinite loop.

Where am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var sitefrom = window.location.href
  var language = sitefrom.search(/portuguese/i);  /* IF language = -1, then site from = SPANISH, otherwise site from is PORTUGUESE */
  var site_es_pt = sitefrom.replace(/spanish/gi, "portuguese");  
  var site_pt_es = sitefrom.replace(/portuguese/gi, "spanish");
  var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
  var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
  var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
  $.ajax({
    url : requestUri,
    contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers : requestHeaders,
    success : onSuccess,
    error : onError
  });

  function onSuccess(data, request){
    var loginName = data.d.Title;

    if(loginName == "*@br.XX.com" && language == -1) {alert(loginName);}

    if (loginName !== "*@br.XX.com" && language !== -1){alert(sitefrom);}

  }

  function onError(error) {
    alert("error");
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above script should not cause infinite loop based on my experience, how you used the script? Try to test by inserting script editor webpart into a page and insert the script into script editor webpart.

And I'll execute custom script before DOM loaded usually.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var sitefrom = window.location.href
            var language = sitefrom.search(/portuguese/i);  /* IF language = -1, then site from = SPANISH, otherwise site from is PORTUGUESE */
            var site_es_pt = sitefrom.replace(/spanish/gi, "portuguese");
            var site_pt_es = sitefrom.replace(/portuguese/gi, "spanish");
            var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
            var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
            $.ajax({
                url: requestUri,
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: requestHeaders,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });
        })      
        function onSuccess(data, request) {
            var loginName = data.d.Title;

            if (loginName == "*@br.XX.com" && language == -1) { alert(loginName); }

            if (loginName !== "*@br.XX.com" && language !== -1) { alert(sitefrom); }

        }
        function onError(error) {
            alert("error");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi Lee,

Thank you for your reply.

Yes, I'm using this script as script editor webpart.

I also tried to run your code and it didn't work.... when I added a reference for jquery and spservices it started looping

<script src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Since I was having issues loading the jquery I found out a different way to redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
var loginName = currentUser.get_email();
var user_country = loginName.search(/br.XX/i);  /* IF country = -1, then user is SPANISH, otherwise user is PORTUGUESE */
var sitefrom = window.location.href
var language = sitefrom.search(/portuguese/i);  /* IF language = -1, then site from = SPANISH, otherwise site from is PORTUGUESE */
var site_es_pt = sitefrom.replace(/spanish/gi, "portuguese");  
var site_pt_es = sitefrom.replace(/portuguese/gi, "spanish");

if(user_country !== -1 && language == -1 && loginName !== "xxxxx@br.XX.com") {window.location = site_es_pt;}
if(user_country == -1 && language !== -1 && loginName !== "xxxxx@br.XX.com") {window.location = site_pt_es;}
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' +     args.get_stackTrace());
}


</script>
```